# Count values in a column if the column header equals a specific value

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula in Excel that will count items in an array that are greater than zero if the column header matches a specified value.  I'm using the COUNTIFS function, and I'm fine with the greater than zero criterion, but I'm struggling with the second criterion.  I've tried using the INDEX and MATCH functions, but I'm not having much success.  Is there a function or formula that will tell Excel to search a two-dimensional array and only count values in the column whose header matches a specific value?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the column header unique, or could the values you're counting come from different columns?

Comment: The column header is unique

Answer (score 2):

Index returns a range, so you can pass it to countifs.  Leave the second criteria blank to return the entire column.  You might use something along the lines of:

`=COUNTIFS(INDEX(datarange,,MATCH(columnname,headerrange,0)),criteria)`

Answer (score 0):

A different solution would be to apply tests to all the value, convert true/false to 1/0, and multiply the arrays.

`{=SUM(N(headerange=columnname)*N(datarange>0))}`

Note this is an array formula.  You do not enter the curly brackets - you enter the formula and press ctrl-shift-enter instead of enter.

This works even when multiple columns are being included in the total.